# How to solve $\int \frac{x^3}{(1+x)^5}\ dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

I am stuck at this integral. Can anybody help or give me a hint what to do with the denominator?

$$\int \frac{x^3}{(1+x)^5} \, dx$$

Comment: Seems doable with partial fractions. Maybe not the fastest method.

Comment: Let $u=1+x$. Then $dx=du$ and $x^3=(u-1)^3$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that\begin{align}\int\frac{x^3}{(1+x)^5}\,\mathrm dx&=\int\frac{((1+x)-1)^3}{(1+x)^5}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int(1+x)^{-2}\,\mathrm dx-3\int(1+x)^{-3}\,\mathrm dx+\\&\phantom{=}+3\int(1+x)^{-4}\,\mathrm dx-\int(1+x)^{-5}\,\mathrm dx.\end{align}Besides$$n\ne-1\implies\int(1+x)^n\,\mathrm dx=\frac1{n+1}(1+x)^{n+1}.$$

Comment: This is equivalent to John's suggestion in the comments to substitute $u = x + 1$ which I find slightly easier as a way to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to integrate by parts:

$$
\int x^2\cdot (1+x)^{-5}\ dx=x^2\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{4}(1+x)^{-4}\right)+\int 2x\cdot \frac{1}{4}(1+x)^{-4}\ dx
$$

and then apply again the rule:

$$
\int 2x\cdot \frac{1}{4}(1+x)^{-4}\ dx= \frac{1}{2}x\left(-\frac{1}{3}(1+x)^{-3}\right)+\int \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}(1+x)^{-3}\ dx
$$

and the last integral is immediate

$$
\int \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}(1+x)^{-3}\ dx=-\frac{1}{12}(1+x)^{-2}+cost
$$

so, summing up all the terms, you get

$$
\int \frac{x^2}{(1+x)^5}\ dx=-\frac{6x^2+4x+1}{12(1+x)^4}+cost.
$$

Comment: In general this idea will work (decreasing the power in both the numerator and denominator until one of them reaches $0$) but it seems to me that there are several errors here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$1+x = 1/t$$ 
$$dx = \frac {-1} {t^2} dt$$
The integral transforms into $$\int \frac {(\frac 1 t -1)^3 } {(\frac 1 t)^5} \frac {-dt} {t^2}$$ $$\int (t-1)^3 dt$$
which can be easily solved further

**Tip** : Whenever the integral contains linear terms with higher powers in the denominator, substituting the linear term with 1/t becomes useful for solving the integral